# Why can't set the password in docker mysql?

Tags: mysql, docker

I created mysql container with docker.

The docker-compose setting is as follows.

```
db:
    image: dockya/db:1.0
    container_name: testdb
    hostname: testdb
    volumes:
      - /home/{{.Node.Hostname}}/share/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test12
    tty: true
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
```

However, when I try to access mysql, I can access it by entering any password other than "test12".

What is the problem?

Comment: add content of your my.cnf  file.

Comment: in my.cnf file, there is only add "[mysqld] bind-address = *".

Comment: What is the `dockya/db` image? It's not on docker hub, as far as I can see.

Comment: @Hans Kilian You can just think of it as "mysql image. I set it like "docker-compose" above without any settings.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether there is the parameter skip-grant-tables in my.cnf file.

Comment: thx for u'r answer. but in my.cnf file, there is only add "[mysqld] bind-address = *".